# how can we do pdf merging using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I wanted to do client side scrpting for merging and splitting pdf, so i wanted to use itextsharp. Can that be used with javascript. I am new to Javascript. Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 13):

I found an entirely client-side solution using the PDF-LIB library: https://pdf-lib.js.org/

It uses the function mergeAllPDFs which takes one parameter: urls, which is an array of urls to the files.

Make sure to include the following in the header:

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js'></script>
```

Then:

```js
async function mergeAllPDFs(urls) {
        
    // create an empty PDFLib object of PDFDocument to do the merging into
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    
    // iterate over all documents to merge
    const numDocs = urls.length;    
    for(var i = 0; i < numDocs; i++) {

        // download the document
        const donorPdfBytes = await fetch(urls[i]).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

        // load/convert the document into a PDFDocument object
        const donorPdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(donorPdfBytes);

        // iterate over the document's pages
        const docLength = donorPdfDoc.getPageCount();
        for(var k = 0; k < docLength; k++) {
            // extract the page to copy
            const [donorPage] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(donorPdfDoc, [k]);

            // add the page to the overall merged document
            pdfDoc.addPage(donorPage);
        }
    }
    
    // save as a Base64 URI
    const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true });

    // strip off the first part to the first comma "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..."
    const data_pdf = pdfDataUri.substring(pdfDataUri.indexOf(',')+1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete code but How do I print this?
I tried
    // Create a new hidden iframe
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Set the content of the iframe to the data URI
    iframe.src = `data:application/pdf;base64,${data_pdf}`;

    // Wait for a while before initiating the print
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

    // Print the PDF
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
and not thing happend.

Comment: I found it! 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65731956/17798537 
Using like `let byteCharacters = atob(data_pdf);`

Answer (score 6):

There are several client-side JavaScript libraries supporting merging and splitting existing PDFs that I'm aware of which might be useful to you:

- [PDF Assembler](https://github.com/DevelopingMagic/pdfassembler) supports this and has a [live demo](https://www.pdfcircus.com/split-join). The [Prior Art / Alternatives](https://github.com/DevelopingMagic/pdfassembler#prior-art--alternatives) part of its README is worth checking out, where several other JavaScript PDF libraries (not necessarily client-side) are mentioned and commented on.
- [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) is a newer library under active development. Similarly, the [Prior Art](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#prior-art) part is worth checking out.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to display multiple PDFs as merged into a single document in the browser, this is surely possible with pdf.js - see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809001/is-there-a-way-to-combine-pdfs-in-pdf-js/40984782#answer-40984782).

Surely that example could also be used to show a specific subset of pages, thus giving the user the ability to split it.

However, if you need the result to be available for download, there's no way (afaik) around server-side processing - at least if you want to stay in the open source, free of charge realm.

---

**Update:** Using a combination of [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) (Mozilla) to render the pdf - which happens on the canvas by default - and [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (parall.ax) one should be able to get the merged result (or even anything else that was drawn on your canvas/es) for download, printing, etc. by using the canvas' `toDataUrl()` approach found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681325/convert-canvas-to-pdf-using-pdf-js) to export page by page (using jsPdf's `addPage` function)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use iTextSharp (a .Net port of iText, which was written in Java) with JavaScript in a browser.

You could use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) in a [Java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet), or there are a couple of PDF libraries for JavaScript if you search (mostly experimental ones, I understand, such as [this one](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) Mozilla did, or [this one](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a merge operation then you can use easy-pdf-merge below is the link :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-pdf-merge

Here is an example:

```
var merge = require('easy-pdf-merge');
merge(['File One.pdf','File Two.pdf'],'File Ouput.pdf',function(err){


    if(err)
    return console.log(err);

    console.log('Successfully merged!');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not for client side.

Comment: Can this be embedded in GAS platform? If yes, how do we do it,pls? Tq

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure JS with [pdfjs-dist](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist):

```
function pdfMerge(urls, divRootId) {
    //necessário pois para manter as promisses sincronizadas com await
    (async function loop() {
        for (url_item of urls) {
            console.log("loading: " + url_item);
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url_item);
            //sem isso fica dessincronizado
            await loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
                pdf.getMetadata().then(function (metaData) {
                    console.log("pdf (" + urls + ") version: " + metaData.info.PDFFormatVersion); //versão do pdf
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('Error getting meta data');
                    console.log(err);
                });
                console.log("páginas: " + pdf.numPages);
                let i = 0;
                while (i < pdf.numPages) {
                    var pageNumber = i;
                    pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        var documentosDiv = document.querySelector('#' + divRootId);
                        documentosDiv.appendChild(div);
                        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        div.appendChild(canvas);
                        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                        var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: 1, });
                        //var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        // Render PDF page into canvas context
                        var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: context,
                            viewport: viewport
                        };
                        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                        renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                            console.log('Page rendered');
                        });
                    });
                    i++;
                }
                // Fetch the first page
            }, function (reason) {
                // PDF loading error
                console.error(reason);
            });
        }
    })();
}
```

html example:

```
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.worker.js"></script>

<h1>Merge example</h1>

<div id="documentos-container"></div>

<style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here https://codepen.io/hudson-moreira/pen/MWmpqPb you have a working example of adding multiple pdfs and combining them into one, all directly from the front-end using the Hopding/pdf-lib library. The layout needs some adjustment but in this example it is possible to dynamically add and remove files directly from the screen.

In short, this function combines the PDFs, but it is necessary to read them in Uint8Array format before applying this function.

```
  async function joinPdf() {
  const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();
  for (let document of window.arrayOfPdf) {
      document = await PDFDocument.load(document.bytes);
      const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(document, document.getPageIndices());
      copiedPages.forEach((page) => mergedPdf.addPage(page));
  }
  var pdfBytes = await mergedPdf.save();
  download(pdfBytes, "pdfconbined" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf", "application/pdf");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using pdfjs on browser (i.e. compiled it to browser environment using parcel)

https://github.com/Munawwar/merge-pdfs-on-browser (folder pdfjs-approach)

Comment: Not sure about the downvote. pdfjs is still a bit rough around the edges. But the fact that it can get many PDFs right on the client-side, without some canvas/image hack, deserves some praise. It generates faster and better quality pdfs than the client-side canvas based answers listed here.

If you really want no issues + high quality, then don't do client-side PDF merging.. use something stable like pdftk on server side.

Answer (score -1):

This is a library for javascript to generate PDFs. It works on the client:

http://parall.ax/products/jspdf#

Another solution would be to make an ajax call, generate the PDF on the server with whatever technology you want to use (itextsharp) and return the generated PDF to the client.

Comment: I don't see any methods in this library to merge two PDFs.  You can just create PDFs from scratch.  Am I looking in the wrong place? https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html