# Convert canvas to PDF

Tags: javascript, canvas, pdf-generation

Is it possible to directly convert canvas to pdf using JavaScript ([`pdf.js`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) or something like that)?

Is there another possible way like canvas to img and then img to pdf?

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can achieve this by utilizing the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library and the [toDataURL](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/) function.

I made a little demonstration:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw a blue cloud
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
context.stroke();

download.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
  var pdf = new jsPDF();

  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<button id="download">download</button>
```

Comment: nice thank you :) and is there any way how to export pdf with same size(width/height) as img?

Comment: It is possible, but you will have to edit the jsPDF library to do that.

Comment: Hmm... attempted, but addImage line returns an error... I think the function may have been replaced?

Comment: @Adil Waqar have you added the jspdf.js file as a script?

Comment: Fixed to use CDN version of library. Previous link had died.

Comment: Why is the download variable being set in the event listener function?

Comment: @MateuszBartkowski As a mistake i presume. It was added when someone edited my answer to have a code snippet.

Comment: Worked perfect! If you prefer to download the JS like I did just visit the page and copy the text into an empty javascript file: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js

Comment: Didn't work in Chrome 72.0 for me. PDF it produces was broken.

Comment: this works fine but my client complain that it will take long time for big images to convert base64 to PDF any solution ?

Comment: The image is always black background, can I change it to transparent or white?

Comment: @rahim.nagori you can use the function in this answer to change the background of image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50126796/2752983

Answer (score 19):

Please see https://github.com/joshua-gould/canvas2pdf. This library creates a PDF representation of your canvas element, unlike the other proposed solutions which embed an image in a PDF document.

```
//Create a new PDF canvas context.
var ctx = new canvas2pdf.Context(blobStream());

//draw your canvas like you would normally
ctx.fillStyle='yellow';
ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
// more canvas drawing, etc...

//convert your PDF to a Blob and save to file
ctx.stream.on('finish', function () {
    var blob = ctx.stream.toBlob('application/pdf');
    saveAs(blob, 'example.pdf', true);
});
ctx.end();
```

Comment: As this library does not simply render canvas to jpeg and put it inside a PDF, it creates a high quality/high resolution pdf

Comment: good library but does not support drawmage() so you cannot add bitmap images on PDF

Comment: Support for images has been added. Please see image example at https://joshua-gould.github.io/canvas2pdf/demo.html.

Comment: Shame that it doesnt support context transformation, ie  ctx.setTransform(2,1,0.5,1,0,1); Image looks the same

Comment: What about a multi-layer canvas?

Comment: With this library I can convert a div element with more elements within it, including background images and that respects the styles with CSS?

Answer (score 12):

So for today, [jspdf-1.5.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf/v/1.5.3).
To answer the question of having the pdf file page exactly same as the canvas. After many tries of different combinations, I figured you gotta do something like this.
We first need to set the height and width for the output pdf file with correct orientation, otherwise the sides might be cut off. Then we get the dimensions from the 'pdf' file itself, if you tried to use the canvas's dimensions, the sides might be cut off again. I am not sure why that happens, my best guess is the jsPDF convert the dimensions in other units in the library.

```
  // Download button
  $("#download-image").on('click', function () {
    let width = __CANVAS.width; 
    let height = __CANVAS.height;

    //set the orientation
    if(width > height){
      pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [width, height]);
    }
    else{
      pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [height, width]);
    }
    //then we get the dimensions from the 'pdf' file itself
    width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
    pdf.addImage(__CANVAS, 'PNG', 0, 0,width,height);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
  });
```

Learnt about switching orientations from here:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/476

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful.

Comment: Absolutely awesome, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be using Kendo ui draw dom to export to pdf-

Suppose the following html file which contains the canvas tag:

```
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script type="x/kendo-template" id="page-template">
     <div class="page-template">
            <div class="header">
              
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="text-align: center">
               
                <h2> #:pageNum# </h2>
            </div>
      </div>
    </script>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <button onclick="ExportPdf()">download</button>
```

Now after that in your script write down the following and it will be done:

```
function ExportPdf(){ 
kendo.drawing
    .drawDOM("#myCanvas", 
    { 
        forcePageBreak: ".page-break", 
        paperSize: "A4",
        margin: { top: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" },
        scale: 0.8,
        height: 500, 
        template: $("#page-template").html(),
        keepTogether: ".prevent-split"
    })
        .then(function(group){
        kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Exported_Itinerary.pdf")
    });
}
```

And that is it, Write anything in that canvas and simply press that download button all exported into PDF.
Here is a link to Kendo UI - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom

Comment: Cool, but prohibitively expensive

Comment: This looked promising, but 1) my chart is wider than tall and got cropped, 2) this seems to import a raster representation which is pixellated, and 3) requires a minimum US$1,000 license - all for a single download link for a single chart in my app ... which can also be done using raster with free libraries :/ "prohibitively expensive" is right.