# Saving SVG pattern as PDF and PNG

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, png

I’ve got a flowery pattern (http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~abp4d9/) where user moves sliders (for inner circles and petals) and flowers change. I’ve got 3 ‘Save as’ buttons. 1st one (SVG) works great. The other 2 work only half-way. The saved file comes up in the appropriate format but then it doesn’t open, saying that there was an error. All 3 JS functions are almost identical – I basically copied them from the working 1st function. I’m not sure what to correct – probably ‘new Blob’ format, but I’m not sure what to put instead. 
So, to sum up:
•   How to get a working ‘Save as SVG’ button to do the same with PDF and PNG?
Here is my JS for half-working PDF button:

```
function downloadPdf(){
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var svg_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
var blob = new Blob([svg_xml]);
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "Pattern.pdf";
a.href = blobURL;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the PNG resp. PDF first. for PNG you can use `canvas` to draw the image and then retrieve the canvas content as PNG (or you can use a library). for PDF you have to use a library.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226677/save-inline-svg-as-jpeg-png-svg?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681325/convert-canvas-to-pdf-using-pdf-js

Comment: The 1st link is really huge JS. It seems to do something very similar to my JS but in a round-about way. The second link doesn't include SVG at all, leave alone pattern. And both use **canvas**. Could I do it without it? As I'm not as far from the answer. My JS actually works and saves as PDF, just doesn't open after. But thanks for answering@pavel