# convert fabricjs object to PDF format rather than simple image?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to convert fabricjs object to PDF not just simple image format. Is there any way we can save file as PDF without server side process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use canvas API's `toDataURL()` method and `jspdf.js` to achieve this. Look at  [Convert canvas to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681325/convert-canvas-to-pdf-using-pdf-js)

Comment: Just an FYI for those who are looking for a real non image solution: The linked solution works as I have used it before, however it converts the canvas to an image and inserts the image into a pdf.