# Dynamically Saving Images to a PDF template

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm building a website where people can pick several pictures from a range.

I then want the users to be able to create a PDF using those pictures.  However I want those pictures inserted in predefined positions and sizes in a template I have already created which will contain other predone materials (words pictures etc).

**So my question :**

1. its possible ?
2. Can anyone recommend a library which will satisfy my needs, I have had a look and I cant see any PDF libraries that seem to mention templates

Any guidance on where to start will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057799/how-to-download-a-png-canvas-image-as-pdf-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible.

I would recommend using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate the pdfs from an html template.

Another handy library for this kind of work is [image.intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

Both of these would work with PHP.

If you're working in javaScript you may want to use [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/)

Comment: Thanks alot for the response, ill take a good look at your links.  It is a node.js project.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**: Only if you use php.

There are several libraries you can use to generate a pdf depending on what template you will build your pdf. I hardly recommend [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/). You can use html to layout the design you want or you can embed the image directly on a page. See an example [here](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/).

Comment: Great thanks alot for the recomendation, ill take a look and put my feedback for others here