# How to print a base64 pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I receive a base64 pdf from the server which I want to print.

I have been trying the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: blahblahblah,
    success: function(data) {
        var printWindow = window.open( "data:application/pdf;base64, " + data );
        printWindow.print();
    }
});
```

Sadly, this does not work in Chrome.  I am receiving the following error:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "xxx" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol
>   of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data".
>   Protocols must match.

Suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: Refer this link I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469412/trigger-print-preview-of-base64-encoded-pdf-from-javascript/45076206#45076206

Comment: ptchand's answer works great in anything above chrome 49, IE 10+, Edge, Safari 7+, Firefox 8+. Just move the data uri into a blob url (all local in the browser) and print the blob off of an iframe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to open your window and try to insert the pdf data as embed.

Here is an piece of code I've found and used fine (I changed to fit on your code, but not tested):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: blahblahblah,
    success: function(data) {

        var winparams = 'dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,'+
            'resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=1050';

        var htmlPop = '<embed width=100% height=100%'
                         + ' type="application/pdf"'
                         + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
                         + escape(data)
                         + '"></embed>'; 

        var printWindow = window.open ("", "PDF", winparams);
        printWindow.document.write (htmlPop);
        printWindow.print();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work.  I believe it is running into the same x-domain problem.  From my reading online, it may not be possible to do this...

Comment: Does your data are binary? In my code, it was returned as string, so I had to use escape(data), maybe it can be the issue here.

Comment: No the pdf renders fine in the window.  I just can't seem to get it to print.  I will examine this deeper later tonight, maybe it is timing problem.

Comment: The page is blank for me

Comment: Not working sir I am passing my base64string inside escape but it only open the blank page with having date at upper left

Comment: This solution dont works on IE 11. There's some alternative?

Comment: This works in some browsers. I found it works in Firefox, but not in chrome. In Chrome I get a PDF with the date at the top?

Comment: This no longer works for me on the latest Chrome update. I switched to one of the answers below.

Answer (score 5):

```
// open PDF received as Base64 encoded string in new tab
const openPdf = (basePdf) => {
  let byteCharacters = atob(basePdf);
  let byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  let file = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf;base64'});
  let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This library works well for us: https://printjs.crabbly.com/

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: blahblahblah,
success: function(base64) {
    printJS({printable: base64, type: 'pdf', base64: true});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use jspdf to do this like

```js
var p=new jspdf();
p.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0); // where imageDate contains base64 string
```