# Join PDF file with AcroFrom - iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, merge, quartz-2d, acrofields

I'm trying to merge some pdf files using Quartz. I success with merge, but some files have acrofields and during merge it seems that I lost those fields.

Does anyone as a suggestion? I'm stucked with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Quartz for anything that involves PDF form fields or comments. Quartz just drops any PDF objects that it doesn't understand and drops dictionaries from objects that it does understand but doesn't know how to process. It is, by far, the worst PDF processor available.

Comment: Thank you, @joelgeraci. There are any alternative?

Comment: If I were assigned this task, I'd offload the merging to a server and use the Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit, iText, or PDFBox in that order of preference. If it needs to happen client side, I'd use PDF.js.

Comment: As a workaround, i'll try to follow this answer [how can we do pdf merging using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984916/2952406) that combines PDF.js and jsPDF.

Comment: do you know any third party sdk that can do the job off-line? With js i'm able to join and to save pdf, but unfortunatley form fields  are dropped, since I convert pdf in jpg and jpg to pdf.

Comment: Wait... so why are you converting to jpg then back to pdf? Of course your fields would be dropped when you do that.

Comment: yes for sure. Finally I ended using Debenu PDF Library Lite, that is free and preserve acro fields during merge. Thanks a lot for your help!