# How to merge multiple images files and PDF files into single PDF using angular 9

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, client-side, angular9

Is it possible to merge multiple images and PDF together into a single pdf and then print? I am using angular 9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917568/1418750

Comment: @nijuguna I am using angular 9. so how to use this example with angular.

Comment: Please add a little bit of code of how you are using it and I can help you. A dummy component could be a good start

Comment: @nijuguna But the issue is, I have a combination of images and pdfs in an array. the above pdf.js example only works for pdfs. do you any solution which works on both the combination of images and pdfs.

Comment: if you cant do this with JavaScript then the answer is no

Comment: @Priyank Angular is a JavaScript framework for making dom changes....so you would just write the JavaScript as ur requirements wont be part of Angular...

Comment: If you could post your code I could help. It is possible, I guess from the docs.

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Is it possible for the combination of Images & PDF and then combine to single pdfs. because I am able to combine the multiple pdfs into single pdf using the link shared by you. but now I am not able to combine images and pdfs together.