# How to print multiple PDF's using print.js in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, printjs

I have tried to print PDF by using [print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) library and it's working fine for single PDF print. now when I am trying to print multiple PDFs, it's throwing an ***error: ERROR Multiple Choices.***. also, I have tried with plain JS but it prompts multiple times for multiple documents.

Below is the code we are using.

```
printJS({ 
         printable: ['dummy.pdf', 'dummy1.pdf'], 
         type:'pdf'
        });
```

please find the attachment.

[image]
Any help much appreciate!!

Comment: Have you tried looping the array of pdfs you wish to print? So sending multiple print commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, after spending 1 week, I am able to print multiple PDF's using print.js in angular 9.
Below are the following steps to print multiple pdfs:

1. Install npm module: PDF-lib

   `npm i pdf-lib`
2. import npm module in the angular file and merge multiple pdfs into single pdfs using below code(say app.components.ts)

   ```
   import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib'
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })

   export class AppComponent {
   title = 'print-multiple-pdfs';

   /* Convert the merged pdf array buffer to blob url for print or open in browser.*/
   downloadFile(data) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    //window.open(url);
    printJS({
      printable: url,
      type: 'pdf',
    })
   }

   async printPDFS() {
    /* Array of pdf urls */
    let pdfsToMerge = ['https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_FlightPlan.pdf']

    const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();
    for (const pdfCopyDoc of pdfsToMerge) {
    const pdfBytes = await fetch(pdfCopyDoc).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    //const pdfBytes = fs.readFileSync(pdfCopyDoc);
    const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
    const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
    copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
      mergedPdf.addPage(page);
    });
   }
   const mergedPdfFile = await mergedPdf.save();
   this.downloadFile(mergedPdfFile);
    }
   }
   ```
3. Call the function for print (app.component.html)

   `<button (click)="printPDFS()">print pdfs</button>`

Reference: [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment print.js doesn't support printing multiple files. I would try to merge the files first into a single file and then printing that one file. This creates one print preview only, providing a better user experience.

as workaround you could use the **onPrintDialogClose** Event

```
printJS({
    printable: 'page01.pdf',
    type: 'pdf',
    onPrintDialogClose: function() {
        printJS('page02.pdf');
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. can you let me know how to merge multiple PDF's into a single file?

Comment: how to merge multiple PDF's into a single file on the client-side?

Comment: @Priyank i would recommend to do it server-side. if this is not possible, there is an example with pdf.js here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809001/is-there-a-way-to-combine-pdfs-in-pdf-js#answers-header

Comment: How we can print pdf and images using the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://printjs.crabbly.com/#documentation)

> *printable* - Document source: pdf or image url, html element id or json
> data object.

It implies to only allow one printable at each time.

So, I'd just try to loop through it's basic usage (call `printJS()` and just pass in a PDF document url)

```
var pdfs_list = ['dummy.pdf', 'dummy1.pdf'];
for (var i = 0; i < pdfs_list.length; i++) {
    printJS(pdfs_list[i]);
}
```

Either that or you concatenate the files server-side like [pbachman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108810/5675325) suggests.

Comment: How we can print pdf and images using the print.js?

Comment: @Priyank if you have a different question, feel free to go ahead and ask. To print images the documentation shows `printJS('images/print-01-highres.jpg', 'image')`. Basically it's the same but you have to pass a second argument called `image`. So, there's different ways you can go about doing that. If you only have .pdf files and images, you can use an if statement inside of the loop and check if that item of the array [contains the letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444497/5675325) `.pdf`; else, use the method with the second argument.

Comment: This doesn't work in practice - only the last document is printed. The reason is that `printJS()` reuses the same iframe, so data from the first call is overwritten by the next one.